# Animation of Ext.Img in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to apply animation at the run time created Ext.Img component in sencha touch 2.0

Comment: To be clear, when the image is `show`n or `initialize`d?

Comment: Also, what have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use CSS3 animations by applying any animation class to the element anytime(not just show) like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('myImageElementId').addCls('popped');
```

where this is popped class

```
.popped {
    -webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```